# Web Crawler with HttpWebRequest/Response

Tags: .net

I am building a web crawler that uses HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse.

I'm fighting through the usual stuff you'd expect doing that such as poor markup and occasional dropped requests retries using exponential backoff but have found something confusing:

After a certain interval of time (or after requests for a certain resource, I haven't identified which yet) all requests start timing out. What I suspected was that the target of the crawl had banned/blocked my IP/useragent and that was the cause, but if I stop my application and start a new instance, requests go through just fine... for a certain interval then resume timing out.

Is there something internal to HttpWebRequest/Response that would cause this? I've set the Requests' KeepAlive to false in case that was an issue but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being a .net bug in how HTTP 1.1 `Connection: keep-alive` works. A host can stop the connection and .net thinks it's still connected. Switching to HTTP 1.0 fixed the issue.